# Scala implicit classes as function arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

I am learning implicit classes and about decorating classes with additional functions and definitions.

https://coderwall.com/p/k_1jzw/scala-s-pimp-my-library-pattern-example

My question is, how to pass these additional functions as arguments to another function.

**Example:**
I defined the class and implicit function like this

```scala
class BlingString(string: String) {
    def bling = "*" + string + "*"
    def doubleBling = "**" + string + "**"
}

implicit def blingYoString(string: String) = new BlingString(string)
```

Now I am able to use these functions on String objects.

```scala
"this is one".bling            // prints *this is one*
"this is two".doubleBling      // prints **this is two**
```

I want to create a generic function by passing these implicit functions to it,

```scala
def blingMyString(name: String, blingFunc: ???)) = name.blingFunc
```

so that I can use this like below,

```scala
blingMyString("this is one", bling)
blingMyString("this is two", doubleBling)
```

This is because I have a class with 20+ additional functions on Spark Dataframe. (data cleansing, data formatting and transformations).

Depending on different scenario, I have to execute one or more functions on dataframes.

```scala
val out1 = df.operation1().operation2().operation3()
val out2 = df.operation1().operation3()
val out3 = df.operation1().operation4().operation3()
```

```scala
def clean(dynamicFn: ???): DataFrame = df.operation1().dynamicFn().operation3()

val out1 = clean(operation2)
val out2 = clean()
val out3 = clean(operation4)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `class` + `implicit def` like this, you can create `implicit class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class BlingString(s: String) { 
   def bling1 = "*" + s + "*"
   def bling2 = "**" + s + "**" 
}
implicit def string2bling(s: String) = new BlingString(s)

def bling(s: String, f: BlingString => String) = f(s)

bling("ciao", _.bling1)
bling("ciao", _.bling2)
```